# Identical OPE behaviour of CFT of T-dual $X’^{\mu}$ of $X^{\mu}$

Tags: operators, string-theory, duality, compactification

In chapter $8$ (String theory vol $\mathrm{I}$) sec $8.3$ Polchinski states that

> The field $X’^{25}$ has same OPE and energy momentum tensor as $X^{25}$ the minus signs always entering in pair

$$X^{25}=X^{25}_L(z)+X^{25}_R(\bar{z})$$
$$X’^{25}=X’^{25}_L(z)-X’^{25}_R(\bar{z})$$

where $X^{25}_{L,R}$ represent $26$-th component of $X^{\mu}$    on which we are doing our identification to compactify the target space?

My doubt is for a general OPE we may get a sign issue for example take OPE of energy momentum with $X’$ the $-$ve sign will persist. Of course energy momentum will be same for the fields since they appear in pair and pairing of antiholomorphic takes care of $-$ve sign.
Did Polchinski have certain OPE in mind while writing this statement?